How to disable scroll wheel zoom in ApexCharts?
I've got a line chart in my app using ApexCharts:
import ApexCharts from "apexcharts";

var options = {
  chart: {
    type: "line",
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: "sales",
      data: [30, 40, 35, 50, 49, 60, 70, 91, 125],
    },
  ],
  xaxis: {
    categories: [1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999],
  },
};

var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);

chart.render();

When I hover the chart and scroll using the mouse wheel, the chart zooms in/out. How do I disable this behavior while still allowing to select areas of the chart to Zoom (just disable the scroll wheel behavior)?
Example

To disable the zoom when using the mouse wheel, you can use the property chart.zoom.allowMouseWheelZoom
For example, the code below disables the zoom for scrolling only (The area can still be zoomed in on by selecting it):
chart = {
  type: "area",
  zoom: {
    enabled: true,
    allowMouseWheelZoom: false
  }
}


Wow, that actually works. How did you know about this property when it's not documented anywhere?

@gespinha I just found it in the source code by name among all the available properties for chart.zoom

Awesome! Thanks!

thanks mate even chatgpt don't know about that property

in your chart object, set chart.zoom.enabled to false
https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/chart/toolbar/#zoom
var options = {
  chart: {
    type: "line",
    zoom: {
      enabled: false,
    }
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: "sales",
      data: [30, 40, 35, 50, 49, 60, 70, 91, 125],
    },
  ],
  xaxis: {
    categories: [1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999],
  },
};


Note: original question did not mention still allowing to select areas of the chart to zoom

If I do that I'll also loose the functionality to select parts of the chart to Zoom. I only want to disable the scroll wheel functionality

@gespinha what exactly do you want? like only be able to zoom when selecting a data point?

Only be able to zoom when you select a portion of the chart by clicking and dragging with the mouse on it.

I don't believe that apexcharts provides that functionality, so you are going to have to implement it yourself, or use another chart library that does have that feature
